# Reload flyspell after changing ispell dictionary

Tags: hooks, flyspell, ispell

Whenever I `ispell-change-dictionary`, I have to disable and re-enable `flyspell-mode` for flyspell to pick up the new dictionary.

Is there a way to automate this? It probably involves a `post-command-hook`, but I'm not sure how this works, especially the disabling and subsequent re-enabling.

Answer (score 1):

You can first check if there is a hook for this function and I found `ispell-change-dictionary-hook`

```lisp
(defun restart-flyspell-mode ()
  (when flyspell-mode
    (flyspell-mode-off)
    (flyspell-mode-on)))
(add-hook 'ispell-change-dictionary-hook 'restart-flyspell-mode)
```

If there is not a hook, you can use `advice-add` like:

```lisp
(defun restart-flyspell-mode (_dict &optional _arg)
  (when flyspell-mode
    (flyspell-mode-off)
    (flyspell-mode-on)))
(advice-add 'ispell-change-dictionary :after 'restart-flyspell-mode)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tested the first snippet and it works. The additional info is very useful as well.

Comment: After restarting emacs a second time, I get the following error upon startup: "Symbol's value as variable is void: flyspell-delayed-commands". It's the same error, regardless of which snippet I use. Very strange.

Comment: I'm quite sure and I update my snippet to not toggle flyspell-mode unless enabled. Can you check if it's working?

Comment: That did the trick!

Comment: Until it didn't, a few restarts later. Totally weird. emacs --debug-init doesn't help. it only says `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable flyspell-delayed-commands)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1556485a5645>)()
  funcall(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1556485a5645>))
  mapc(funcall (#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1556485a5645>)))` and then gives the config file. So strange that it works only once.

Comment: @henning Sorry, I cannot reproduce with `emacs -Q`. Maybe you should check you configs.

Comment: Yes, it is probably some idiosyncrasy. Thanks for your help, though. I'll get it working somehow. ;)